# How can I have more descriptive directions then "unknown road" to "unknown road" in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, maps, directions

I have items on a map, I would like to give directions to those items. For each map I have a title, and a geopoint (lat, lon). I know that I can send a directions intent using the following :

```
Uri uri= Uri.parse( "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + currentLocation.getLatitude() + "," + currentLocation.getLongitude() + "&daddr="+mapItem.lat + "," + mapItem.lon );
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
mActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

This works perfectly except the directions are between "Unknown Road" and "Unknown Road". I was wondering if I could pass the title of my map item and also "Current Location" so the directions activity can be more descriptive.

The goal would be to have directions from "Current Location" to "The White House"